# Is function $f: \Bbb{Z^+} \to \Bbb{Q}$ a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$f: \Bbb{Z^+} \to \Bbb{Q}$, is this function a sequence? I thought it is because the domain is part of the positive integers and the codomain rational number is a subset of the real numbers.

Comment: The codomain seems to be the set of rational numbers, not irrational.

Comment: What is your definition of a sequence?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a sequence? Well, that depends entirely on what your *exact* definition of sequence is.

However, there is no doubt that any function with the positive integers as domain can be viewed as, or reinterpreted as, a sequence. That is, there is a clear and canonical bijective correspondence between functions $f$ with the positive integers as domain, and the resulting sequences
$$
f(1), f(2), f(3), \ldots
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your definition of "sequence" is "a function from the positive integers to the reals"; in that case, formally, $f$ is not a sequence, because two functions are the same if they have the same domain, codomain, and "rule", and your $f$ has the wrong codomain.

On the other hand, there's a function (called "inclusion") 
$$
i: \Bbb Q \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto x
$$
that considers each rational number as a real number. The function $g = i \circ f$ is a function from $\Bbb Z^+ \to \Bbb R$ with the property that $g(n) = f(n)$ for every $n$ in the domain (i.e., $g$ "looks just like" $f$), and $g$ actually *is* a sequence.

Eliding such inclusion functions is really common in mathematics (we say "a rational number is a real number" or "the rationals are reals"), so as Arthur says, your function $f$ "can be viewed as" or "reinterpreted as" a sequence.

Does this distinction matter? Do the constant "puns" in mathematics every really make a difference? For the working mathematician, they seldom do, except that they tend to make proofs and even theorem statements a little shorter. But if you try to formalize things, and prove that a proof of some theorem is correct by encoding into a proof-assistant or proof-checker, they become critically important. In the last year, I've been trying to use Isabelle/HOL, and elided inclusions can be something of a nightmare there.

The other place inclusions show up a good deal is in algebraic topology, where the inclusion map from a subspace into a space induces a homomorphism of homology groups that is often *not* the identity map, so explicitly naming the inclusion map is critical.